# Defined a function without using any language extensions, but must use a language extension to declare its type?

Tags: haskell, types, error-handling, monads

I've defined a custom error type that I want to use with the Error monad.  For the sake of example, here's a dummy one:

```
newtype CustomError = CustomError String
instance Error CustomError where
  strMsg = CustomError
```

I'd like to define a `throwCustomError` function that works like `throwError`, but instead of just throwing the string it's given, it uses it to create a `CustomError` and then throws *that*.  This definition works:

```
-- | Throws a 'CustomError' containing the given error message.
throwCustomError msg = throwError $ CustomError msg
```

However, I'd like to add a type declaration, mainly so that Haddock will include the function's description in the generated documentation.  If I use `:t` in GHCI, it tells me that the type of this function is `MonadError CustomError m => String -> m a`, and that makes sense to me, but if I write

```
throwCustomError :: MonadError CustomError m => String -> m a
```

GHC complains about a "non-variable type argument" and tells me I have to use `-XFlexibleContexts` to permit it.  Why do I have to use a language extension to *declare* a function of this type, when I can *define* a function of this type without using any language extensions?  Is there a way to declare this function's type without using language extensions?

---

On a separate note, I originally tried defining the function as

```
throwCustomError = throwError . CustomError
```

but GHC tells me "No instance for `(MonadError CustomError m0)` arising from a use of `throwError`".  I don't quite understand why this definition isn't equivalent to the other one; they both mean the same thing as far as I can see.

---

Taking a step back:  should I even bother defining this function?  Or should I just write `throwError $ strMsg "foo"` when I want to throw an error?  (Currently I have `throwError "foo"` throughout my code, so I need to change those lines either way.)

Comment: Your final example smells of the monomorphism restriction. Try disabling it or adding a type signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the `Error` monad, you're already relying on extensions, most notably `MultiParamTypeClasses` and `FunctionalDependencies`, so I'm not sure that there is any point in trying to keep your code extension-free.

There are some extensions which have some potentially nasty side-effects (e.g. `IncoherentInstances`), and there's certainly a point to keeping usage of those to a minimum, but extensions like `FlexibleContexts` are completely harmless.

Comment: Currently I don't have to use any `-X` options when compiling my code, which is what I'd like to preserve.  I'm less concerned with extensions that I get "for free" through libraries in the Haskell Platform.  Strangely, I'd tried `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` and it didn't seem to work, but I tried it again just now and it does.